# iOS 7 Safari: OS locks up for 4 seconds when clicking/focusing on a HTML input

Tags: iphone, ipad, input, safari, ios7

**UPDATE: The issue seems to stem from having many select elements on a page. How random is that?**

So here's the issue. On iOS 7 Safari, when tapping the a text input on my site, the keyboard opens then freezes the OS for about 2-5 seconds then finally scrolls to the input. After this happens once, it never happens again until you refresh the page. I've looked all over the place, and yes, iOS 7 Safari is super buggy, but lets try and see if we can figure this out.

Note: This does not happen in any other mobile browser or any previous iOS Safari. It happens both on the ios 7 iphone and ios 7 ipad.

I will list everything my friend and I have tried so far:

- Removed the ability to add event handlers in jQuery. (Note: all our event handlers are assigned through jQuery except for unload and onpageshow).
- Removed the jQuery autocomplete script from the inputs.
- Removed all JavaScript from the inputs.
- Removed all third-party libraries being added on the page by rejecting the domains on the Mac.
- Switched back to previous jQuery versions. The last one we could actually use before nothing worked was 1.7.0.
- Switched back to previous jQuery UI versions.
- Changed input event handling to delegate and live, instead of on('click')
- Removed all  CSS classes.
- Removed all CSS from the page. Note: The response time for the OS this went down to 1-2 seconds but still happened.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: not an anwswer but its happening in other sites too: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5477570?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: This issue still exist in iOS8 in safari

Comment: This isn't relegated to select elements.  In fact, I'm experiencing this issue with a single input box with no css and no javascript whatsoever.  This is definitely a head scratcher.  It works on google's website for example.  I've emulated what google does with their box and I STILL get the issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(There are some somewhat-effective solutions, see near the end of the list)

At my company we are also suffering from this. We filed an issue with Apple but have heard mum.

Here are some interesting jsfiddles to help illustrate some of the issues, it definitely seems to revolve around the number of hidden fields, and textareas do not seem to be affected.

From debugging efforts, my guess is that there is some functionality trying to detect if an input is a credit card or phone number or some special kind which seems to cause the locking behavior. This is just one hypothesis though..

**Summary:**

On a page with a form containing named input elements inside containers that are marked "display: none", the first press on an input in that form has a very noticeable delay (20sec-2min) between the keyboard coming up and the input being focused. This prevents users from using our web app due to the enormous time spent with the ui frozen waiting for the keyboard to respond. We have debugged it in various scenarios to try and discern what is going on, and it appears to be from a change in how iOS7 parses the DOM versus how it did on iOS6, which has none of these issues.

From debugging within Safari's Inspector with the iPad connected, we found that iOS7 provides much more information about the (program)'s activities, to the point that we found that _CollectFormMetaData is the parent of the problem. Searching for meta data causes massive churn that increases more than linearly along with the number of hidden containers containing inputs. We found that _isVisible and _isRenderedFormElement are called far more than they reasonably should be. Additionally, if it helps, we found some detection functions relating to credit cards and address books were large time consumers.

Here are some jsFiddles for illustration. Please view them in Safari on an iPad running iOS6 and then on an iPad running iOS7:

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/20/ - Runs fine on both

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/21/ - Just noticeable delay on iOS 7

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/22/ - More noticeable delay on iOS 7

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/29/ - VERY noticeable delay on iOS 7

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/30/ - Same as 29 but with none hidden - no delay on iOS 7

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/38/ - Same as 29 but further exacerbated

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/39/ - 99 hidden inputs, one visible, one separately visible

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/40/ - 99 hidden textareas, one visible, one separately visible

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/41/ - 99 hidden inputs, one visible, one separately visible, all 
with the autocomplete="off" attribute

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/42/ - 99 hidden inputs, one visible, one separately visible. Hidden by position absolute and left instead of display.

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/63/ - Same as gUDvL/43/ but with autocomplete, autocorrect, autocapitalize, and spellcheck off

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/65/ - Same as gUDvL/63/ but with cleaned up indentation (seems slower on iPad)

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/66/ - Same as gUDvL/65/ but with display none via css again instead of DOMReady jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/67/ - Same as gUDvL/66/ but with TedGrav's focus/blur technique

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/68/ - Same as gUDvL/66/ but with css driven text-indent instead of display:block again **(noticeable improvement - reduction to 2-3 secs for initial focus)**

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/69/ - Same as gUDvL/68/ but with TedGrav's focus/blur re-added

http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/71/ - Same as gUDvL/66/ but with js adding a legend tag before each input. **(noticeable improvement - reduction to 2-3 secs for initial focus)**

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" /> (links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code..)
```

(We should note that having the iPad connected to a Mac with Safari's debugger engaged dramatically emphasizes the delays.)

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Load any of the above jsfiddles on the iPad
2. Press an input to gain focus
3. Watch screen until you can type

**Expected Results:**

Expect to be able to type as soon as the keyboard pops up

**Actual Results:**

Watch the keyboard pop up and the screen freeze, unable to scroll or interact with Safari for a duration. After the duration, focus is given as expected. From then on no further freezes are experienced when focusing on inputs.

**tl;dr technique summary**

So overall there are a couple proposed fixes from various answers:

- Don't hide the divs with display: none - use something like text-indent
- Short circuit Apple's metadata scanning logic - many form tags or legend tags seem to do the trick
- Auto focus/blur - Did not work for me but two people reported it did

**Related threads at Apple:**

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5468360

Comment: No I do not as we filed it with a different developer's account that I do not have access too and he has not gotten back to me. As far as I know they were completely mum. We are still suffering from this issue and can easily recreate it with the latest 7.1.1 release. No word form Apple, many, many angry customers. I've since tried different combinations, like with autocomplete, autocorrect, autocapitalize, spellcheck, and novalidate attributes to no avail.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue on the jsfiddles (ipad) but the legend tag work around reduced the page I was having issues with from ~4s delay to ~1s delay (on the same ipad as I tried the fiddles with).

Comment: Adding the legend tag before all inputs was the most effective for my form. I have ~90 text inputs, due to pagination a majority is hidden at any one time. Delay is still definitely noticable, but it's in the realm of ~1s which means that by the time someone has started typing, it's responsive again.

Comment: I had the issue with a large number of text input fields, a lot of them where hidden on load and you page through to undhide them.
I found adding the legend by itself may have improved it but still caused a delay. However adding an autofocus to the first input field as well as a legend fixed the problem for me, I am now down from up to a minute to about 1/2 a second

Comment: @ak85 To clarify, when you say you added an autofocus to the first input - was that just the autofocus attribute or JavaScript triggering a focus event?

Comment: This supports my findings in the profiler in Safari in debug mode. iPhone 4s connected via usb (issue not apparent in simulator) Significant time seen on these calls (not included in any javascript must be safari):
_isRenderedFormControl
_searchForLabelsAfterElement
_searchForLabelsBeforeElement
_matchesForElement
_bestMatchForElement
_addressBookLabelForElement
_looksLikeMonthField
_looksLikeCreditCardTypeField
_looksLikeYearField
_looksLikeCreditCardNumberField
_looksLikeCreditCardCardholderField
_looksLikeDayField
_looksLikeSocialSecurityNumberField
_looksLikeCreditCardSecurityCodeField

Comment: One thing worth noting is that the input and select elements don't need to be named to reproduce this issue. I can confirm this issue is still happening on iOS 11.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be a problem with how IOS handles the *touch-event* for inputs and textareas. The delay gets larger when the DOM gets larger. There is however not a problem with the focus event!

To work around this problem you can override the **touchend** event and set focus to the input/textarea.

```
document.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {  
     if (e.target.nodeName.toString().toUpperCase() == 'INPUT' || e.target.nodeName.toString().toUpperCase() == 'TEXTAREA') {  
         e.preventDefault(); 
         e.target.focus(); 
     } 
});
```

This will however create a new problem. It will let you scroll the page while touching the input/textarea, but when you let go, the site will scroll back to the original position.

To fix this, you just need to check if any scrolling has occured, and surround the *preventDefault* and *target.focus* with an if statement.

To set the original position, you can use the **touchstart** event.

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
    ... //store the scrollTop or offsetHeight position and compare it in touchend event.
}
```

**EDIT** Me and a colleague have improved it a little bit, and it works like a charm.

```
var scroll = 0; 
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) { 
    scroll = document.body.scrollTop; 
 });   

document.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) { 
    if (scroll == document.body.scrollTop) { 
        var node = e.target.nodeName.toString().toUpperCase(); 
        if (node == 'INPUT' || node == 'TEXTAREA' || node == 'SELECT') { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            e.target.focus(); 
            if(node != 'SELECT') {
                var textLength = e.target.value.length; 
                e.target.setSelectionRange(textLength, textLength);
            }
        } 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, this code makes all the inputs act very slow or even unresponsive at times.

Comment: @JornvandeBeek that's wierd. Thought this would work for everyone because it solved the problem for all of our apple devices. Only tried it on one site though. Maby you have some other code interfering with the *touch* events?

Comment: That might be the case, so I removed the `node == 'INPUT' ||` part to just make it do its magic on textarea and select nodes. In our case, the hanging was occurring dependably, but either on a select element or on a textarea element.

In the end the code did not prevent hanging on a textarea in all cases, but after shuffling around that element a bit that was gone and it did alleviate hanging on an earlier select element.

Comment: Thanks Binke... This is simply Excellent work around :)

Answer (score 4):

Struggled with this issue as well within an ios fullscreen which was inserting /removing pages containing a single input element. Was experiencing delays up to 30 seconds with only a single visible text input element on the page (and within the entire DOM). Other dynamically inserted pages with single or multiple text inputs in the same webapp were not experiencing the input delay. Like others have mentioned, after the initial delay, the input field would behave normally on subsequent focus events (even if the dynamic page containing the input element was removed from the DOM, then dynamically re-rendered/inserted back into the DOM).

On a hunch based on the above behaviour, tried the following on page load:

$("#problem-input").focus();
$("#problem-input").blur();

While the above executes immediately with no delay, the end result is no subsequent delays when the input gets focus via user interaction. Can't explain the reason behind this working, but it appears to work consistently for my app while other suggested fixes have failed.

Comment: Great idea, it does not seem to work for us though. Could you check this jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/gUDvL/67/

Answer (score 3):

I have the same `freezeing` problem.

I am not sure we're in the same situation.

here is my demo:http://tedzhou.github.io/demo/ios7sucks.html

In my page, i use a `<p>` element with `onclick` attribute as a *button*.
When user click on the *button*, page change to a `textarea`.
Then a click on it will freezes the browser.

The time freezing spent relevent to the numbers of the dom elements.
In my pages, there are 10000 elements, which make it freeze by 10+ seconds.

We can solve the problem by switching the `<p>` element to the real `<button>`, or reducing the nums of dom elements.

ps: sorry for my poor english.  LOL

Comment: For me the situation was the opposite. I had a button with an onclick handler and there was a 10 second delay before the UI was active again after clicking on the button, even if the button just did an alert and nothing more. I replace the <button> with an <a> tag and returned false from the anchor onclick handler. After this change the hanging issue was resolved in the web application. I wish I knew more about what is causing this in iOS because it is a very annoying bug.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue for me was with hidden fields.  Made the form hang for 10-15 seconds.

I managed to get around by positioning the hidden form fields off the screen.

---

To hide:

```
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
```

To show:

```
position: relative;
left: 0;
```

---

Comment: This does make a noticeable difference to the speed, but does not completely ameliorate the issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

Met the same problem in quite complex application having many inputs.

Attached debugger to Safari iOS7 via USB and logged UI events. I see "touchend" event coming as soon as I am clicking on textarea (or any input) and in 10-20 seconds after that I see "click" being dispatched.

Clearly it is a bug in Safary as on other devices like Android or iOS6 there is no problem with the very same application.

Answer (score 1):

It happens not only in iOS but in safari 7 for MAC OS (Maverics) too, I have found that the problem happens when you use a lot of div tags to contain inputs (or selects) within a form:

```
<div> <select>...</select> </div>
<div> <select>...</select> </div>
...
```

I changed the layout of my selects to use ul/li and fieldsets instead of divs and the freezze time was reduced drastically.

```
<ul>
   <li><select>...</select></div>
   <li><select>...</select></div>
</ul>
```

Here are two examples in jsfiddle:

freezze for 5 seconds

http://jsfiddle.net/k3j5v/5/

freeze for 1 second

http://jsfiddle.net/k3j5v/6/

I hope it might help someone

Comment: Interesting of course but even 1 sec delay for focus event is not an option. In our case we do not have that many selects but rather other focusable elements like hyperlinks, buttons, etc. And only few of them are visible and so focusable. Seems like Safari scans all DOM elements as focus candidates when it tries find focusable.  target.

Comment: also if the elements are somehow not visible the freezze time is bigger

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue was being caused by user inputs being hidden on the page with `display:none`.

The workaround I used: instead of hiding inputs with `display:none`, I used jQuery's `detach()` method on document ready to 'hide' all the user inputs that were not being used. Then `append()` the inputs when they were needed.

That way no inputs had `display:none` on when the page was first loaded and so no delay occurred on the initial user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same or a similar problem at my company. Whenever we displayed a large number of drop down lists and then a user clicked on a drop down, IOS 7 would freeze the page for a minute or two. After it unfroze, everything would work properly from that point forward.

This affected all input types. The large number of drop downs were actually hidden on first load - the user would initiate the display of the drop downs. Until the drop downs were displayed - everything would work fine. As soon as they were displayed, the next input click, even an input that had been working properly, now would cause the browser to freeze.

As others have noted, it seems that IOS 7 has a problem when parsing the visible inputs in the DOM after the user first interacts with an input. When the number and/or complexity of the elements/options/DOM are higher, the freeze is more pronounced.

Because it always froze on the initial user interaction, we decided to initiate a hidden user action as soon as we displayed the list of drop downs. We created a transparent button (it could not be hidden - it had to be "displayed") and initiated a click on it as soon as the user opened the drop down list. We thought that this would make IOS start parsing the DOM quicker, but found that it actually fixed the problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem as well since I noticed many people are still having a problem with this I thought I'd put my solution.

Basically my solution is server side hiding of elements. 
My page is ASP.NET so I wrapped my divs with the inputs with Panels and set these panels as Visible false.
This way if I click on an input the safari can't see all the other controls since they are hidden server side.

Of course if you want to make this work a little like clientside jquery you'll need automatic postback and an updatepanel somewhere.
This solution requires an effort but still its better than actually trying to fix a safari bug.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be slightly off the main topic, but I did arrive here after some searching as the scenario "feels" similar.

**Issue:**

My issue felt like a lockup in iOS, but not quite, since other elements on the page were still interactive. I had an `<input type="search" />` element, that would not focus when I clicked into the field. But it would eventually catch focus after about 4-5 taps on the screen.

**Additional Info:**

My project is a hybrid app: WebView inside of an iOS app. The site is built with Twitter Bootstrap.

**Solution:**

I happened to also have the `autofocus` attribute set on the element. I tried removing that and it worked... no more consecutive taps to get the field to focus.

Answer (score 0):

## iOS 12.1.1 - December 2018

Here is a simple fix that worked in my case:

`window.scrollTo(0,0)`  // attached to 'blur' event for the input fields

While it may not be ideal in terms of UX (especially if you have a form with many fields), it's definitely better than having 10+ second freezing time.

Answer (score -2):

have you tried to turn off "Password & Autofill" > "Credit Cards" into Safari settings ?
After this operation it works fine. This isn't a final solution but maybe the problem's reason on iOS.