# iOS7 Mobile Web input/select elements freezes OS

Tags: html, input, ios7, mobile-website

In my site I've encountered OS freeze when interacting with my input elements. also happens with select elements. The freeze is for about 20-30 seconds. after that, the keyboard appears and another freeze for 5-10 seconds and then it's ok.
From that point on, everything runs ok.

Also happens on iOS7.1

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have an example link?

Comment: Check my answer at: 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335109/ios-7-safari-os-locks-up-for-4-seconds-when-clicking-focusing-on-a-html-input/23606434#23606434