# Number of Select Options cause a slow response to text entry on an iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, dom

I have a standard HTML form with CSS styling.

Everything works fine however when testing on an iPad (both iOS7 and 8) it is very slow (approx 1-2 seconds) to respond to key presses on the native keyboard when trying to enter text in to the form fields.

I tried removing elements from the page to work out what is causing this issue and it appears to be the select boxes.  Especially the 'Nationality' field which has in excess of 100 selectable values.

I tried this on other peoples' live form and the same problem appeared so I believe this is an iPad/iOS issue.

Has anyone uncounted this and do you know a workaround?

Kind regards,

Comment: I suspect this relates to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335109/ios-7-safari-os-locks-up-for-4-seconds-when-clicking-focusing-on-a-html-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F.Y.I This was an iPad/iOS issue that was fixed in iOS 8.1.3